# How to make an aoutorun for a CD to open an HTML forn MAC and Windows

Tags: autorun

Hi I am trying to make an autorun.inf to open an html like this:

```
[Autorun]
Open=Start index.html
```

And like this:

```
[Autorun]
Open=starterfile.exeindex.html
```

Non is working.

In the other hand can I make Mac open the file straight away?

Comment: You just don't. Autorun was a major hazard in the old days. Now it's disabled by default on every system I know of.

Comment: Thanks @Bart, so people now are allow to surf the CD as they want? You know if there is a way to hide folders, in that way they can see only the file I want they open.

Comment: I found this by the way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735412/how-to-make-an-html-page-open-automatically-on-a-cd-dvd It's a bit old but maybe it can help. I wouldn't hide to much. Just give your files good names so it's more obvious.